# how do I print the value of nodes in a binary tree, that have been added to a queue?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am writing code to solve the following Leetcode solution:
https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/

```
#THIS FIRST CHUNK OF CODE IS JUST TO BUILD A BINARY TREE!

from collections import deque
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, val):
        # Compare the new value with the parent node
        if self.val:
            if val <= self.val:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = TreeNode(val)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(val)
            elif val >= self.val:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = TreeNode(val)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(val)
        else:
            self.val = val

    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print(self.val),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()

#THIS IS THE CODE TO SOLVE THE LEETCODE PROBLEM
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        queue = deque()
        if not root:
            return []
        if root.left:
            queue.append(root.left)
        if root.right:
            queue.append(root.right)

        right_subt = []
        left_subt = []

        while queue:
            level_length = len(queue)
            for _ in range(level_length // 2):
                node = queue.popleft()
                left_subt.append(node.val)
                if node.left:
                    queue.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    queue.append(node.right)
            for _ in range((level_length - (level_length // 2))):
                node = queue.popleft()
                right_subt.append(node.val)
                if node.left:
                    queue.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    queue.append(node.right)
            print(queue)

            if left_subt != right_subt.reverse():
                return False
        return True

root = TreeNode(1)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(4)
root.insert(4)
root.insert(3)
root.PrintTree()

x=Solution()
Solution.isSymmetric(x,root)
```

My code fails the first `input: root = [1,2,2,3,4,4,3]` ; it should `return True` but it is `retuning False`, and I am trying to debug it.

In my code above I build a tree using class TreeNode, and I try to print the queue, however what I get is: `deque([<__main__.TreeNode object at 0x7fe9381dc340>, <__main__.TreeNode object at 0x7fe9381dc820>])`

Any ideas how I can print the queue to show the node values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elegant would be to define the `__repr__` function for the TreeNode class, e.g.

```
    def __repr__(self):
        
        return f"Node {self.val}"
```

This determines how the TreeNode class is printed. In this case you get

```
deque([Node 2, Node 3])
```

Then you can also adapt it according to your needs, e.g. if you want to print left and right in addition to the value.

Comment: Thanks mcsoini, would the def __repr__(self) be in place of __init__(self)? or would I have the code just added as a batch to the bottom of the TreeNode class?

Comment: That would be an additional method of the TreeNode class, so yes: At the bottom.

Comment: Hi mcsoini, quick question, is there a big difference between using str() and repr()- I've looked online and it seems there isn't much of a difference apart from say if you wanted to check rounding errors, and that repr is used more for debugging and str more for printing an output a certain way for presentation. Any other major difference?

Comment: I think it's really just those subtleties you mention. In your case it arguably doesn't make a difference.